# How to locate the text of table header at center in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

How can I locate the text of HTML5 table header at center in CSS3?

If I write `text-align: center;`, it works on `td`, but not on `th`. However, some web pages say that you can use `text-align: center;` on both `td` and `th`. But, there are also [some sites](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/stylish-css-tables-tutorial) that don't use `text-align: center;` on `th`, but nonetheless place it at center (and I don't know why).

So why does the `text-align: center;` not work on `th`? And how can I locate it at center?

Comment: for <th> by default the text will appear in center.

Comment: You are going to need to post your code, preferably in a jsFiddle or something like that, so that we can see. In short: `text-align: center;` is a default style setting on `th`, and yes, you can set it yourself. So there's no reason why you should be encountering this issue, unless something else is doing it. So: post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following code caused all the messes:

```
.blog {
    text-align: left;
}
```

and within `<div class=blog>...</div>` are my tables, which would be affected by the above setting.

That said, I don't know why then only `th` was affected, and `td` was NOT, by the above setting. Also, if I write the following code:

```
table th, td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

the text location succeeded. However,

```
th, td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

doesn't work on `th`, but work on `td` for some reasons.

I don't know why such inconsistency occurs, but for the time being, I had both `th` and `td` located at center. Thanks for those who left comments.

Comment: Your issue is likely related to one of specificity. If you don't learn about it, you're going to run into many of the same issues as you have right now. Perhaps read [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for a primer.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me here!
http://jsfiddle.net/vuXL3/

Just applied `text-align: center;` to the `th`.